# Для чего в Visual Studio папка решения и содержимые в ней файлы и как получить доступ к этим данным из проектов?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Я создал в одном решении Visual Studio несколько проектов. Можно добавить папку решения и файлы в нее,насколько я понял,относящиеся ко всем проектам сразу.  Но толи из за проблемы с namespace толи из за того,что я не знаю доступа- я не могу из файлов проекта получить значения из “общего для всех класса”.
Вообщем я хочу создать один общий статический класс в этой папке для всех проектов сразу и в нем хранить параметры и иметь к ним доступ со всех проектов данного решения.
Как такое сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классический вариант - выделите общие части ваших проектов в отдельный проект и поместите его в решение. А в целевых проектах добавьте на ссылку на этот общий проект и его публичные классы будут доступны обычным образом, по полному имени (с указанием пространства имен) или короткому, если пространство имен указано в первых директивах using.

Comment: .Я создал в папке решения static класс Settings и он лежит в неймспейсе NamespaceSettings . Когда я пытаюсь подключить этот неймспейс в проектах-студия ничего не видит

Comment: @RakzinRoman так это не будет работать, студия так устроена. В папку решения можно сложить документацию, возможно отдельные ресурсные файлы, но код должен быть оформлен проектом.

Comment: @RakzinRoman ну и не забудьте в референсы добавить ссылку на общий проект, но об этом я уже написал.

Comment: класс публичный,статический. Но при попытке написать using NamespaceSettings,студияругается. Все проекты получается изолированы и никак не связаны с общим файлом,хотя находятся в одном решении

Comment: Еще раз. Добавляете в решение новый проект, именно проект а не папку. В нем создаете общие для всех классы. После этого, в нужных проектах тыкаете правой кнопкой в папку refferences и добавляете ссылку на ваш общий проект.

Comment: ураа）спасибо, ато я неск дней хочу уже это сделать,что б менять значение в одном месте и все проекты сразу брали от туда. Спасибо

Comment: а когда все проекты разнесутся по разным местам-ошибок не будет от отсутствия зависимостей?или это на этапе компиляции значения возьмутся,скомпилируются и потом каждый проект живет своей жизнью（ну я так планирую сделать）,нужно только в момент компиляции взять параметры

Comment: @RakzinRoman при компиляции, DLL общего проекта будет лежать в папке проектов, которые на него ссылаются

Comment: я понял,тогда,наверное,я не верно задал вопрос. Я просто хочу создать общие параметры для всех проектов,например адрес сервера,порт и др и все проекты должны брать это одно и тоже значение. Сейчас я руками переписываю везде,когда надо изменить сервер,а этот вариант сделает клиентские приложения зависимыми,а мне нужно только параметр подставить,изменив его в одном месте. Как такое сделать,не знаете? Либо какойнибудь прекомпилятор существует,что б он подставил значения перед компиляцией?или я слишком усложняю?

Comment: @RakzinRoman да это совсем другой вопрос. Тут придется подумать, так с ходу не скажу.